Welcome to our new pro tem moderators!
Thanks to everyone who participated in the recent nominations to select new moderators. We're always happy to see the community being proactive and getting involved in who is leading their site. Now, I'm happy to announce that your site has two new pro tem moderators who have stepped up and volunteered their time to help lead this site to success. Here they are:




I'd also like to thank two of our past moderators for everything they've done for this site up until this point. Their moderator status is being removed at this time as well:




Good luck to the new moderators, and good luck to the site as a whole!

Welcome to the new moderators! :D 
I'll be glad to assist you if and when needed, just let me know.*

*Possibly by ping, I can't hear your voices. :P 
